# UNIX Pthreads & mutex; program locks up

Tags: c, multithreading

Following scenario:

We are supposed to make x Threads maximum. Our main-function is supposed to make a single new thread with a pointer to the function 'makeThreads'. This function is supposed to make up to 2 threads, depending on how many threads are already there. Race conditions are to avoid.
I'm stuck. I'm not exactly sure how to solve the problem I'm running into, partly because I don't can't identify the problem itself.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_THR 20

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int threadCount = 0;

int randomNbr(){
    int number = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    return number;
}

void *makeThreads(void* number){

    int rndnmb = *((int *) number);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    sleep(rndnmb);
    pthread_t threadDummy;
    int thread1, i, threadID, rndnbr;

    threadID = threadCount;
    printf("Hello from Thread %d!\n", threadID);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(threadCount < MAX_THR){
            rndnbr = randomNbr();
            int *rnd = &rndnbr;
            threadCount++;
            thread1 = pthread_create(&threadDummy, NULL, *makeThreads, (void *) rnd);
            pthread_join(threadDummy, NULL);

        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    printf("Goodbye from Thread %d!\n", threadID);
}

int main(){

    int t1, rndnbr;

    pthread_t threadOne;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    srand(time(NULL));
    rndnbr = randomNbr();
    int *rnd = &rndnbr;
    threadCount++;
    t1 = pthread_create(&threadOne, NULL, *makeThreads, (void *) rnd);
    pthread_join(threadOne, NULL);

}
```

Comment: you create a thread, which locks the mutex and creates a new thread, which does the same. The first one blocks the second and waits for the second to end.

Comment: So, it doesn't wait until the mutex is unlocked, it just locks him again? Did I misunderstand mutex?

Comment: no, the second thread waits for the mutex(at the pthread_mutex_lock) and the first thread waits for the end of the second (at the pthread_join). So they block each other.

Comment: So, if I make the threadcreation outside of the mutex and get the relevant data(threadcount etc) in the mutex, it shouldnt block anymore?

Comment: yes, and don't forget to return something at the end of your functions.